# How to customise allure report with java

Tags: java, testng, allure

I want to customise my allure report like adding description for a test, or the steps carried out in the test. I know we can do this by using @description tag in javascript but how do I do this in Java. I'm using testng for the test, allure for reporting and working in eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need the below import

```
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.annotations.Description;
```

and the you have to just add @Description annotation to your test.

```
@Description("Test Description goes here")
public void Test001(){
  // steps goes here
}
```